$2$ continuous, commuting functions doesn't always have a common fixed point
The question is as such:

If two continuous mappings $f$ and $g$ of a closed interval into itself commute, that is, $f\circ g=g\circ f$, then they do not always have a common fixed point.

-- Zorich Mathematical Analysis I
I have not managed to find a counterexample case myself. Could you help me?

If $f(x)=x$, then $g(x), g^2(x),\ldots$ are also fixed points of $f$ (and vice versa, of course), and these points are all distinct, and none is a fixed point of $g$. This suggests that there is no very easy construction of such functions, and the references you already found perhaps cannot be substantially improved on.

@ChristianRemling Thank you I will check the papers more thoroughly.

It says "two functions", no mention of "continuous"?

@GeraldEdgar: of course I assume continuous was meant as a hypothesis. I edited the question to improve the writing and overall presentation.

Thank you @SamHopkins

Looking at one of the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450803, it seems this problem in the textbook in question was changed; the original statement was essentially the negation of the current version. I suspect that the author of the textbook may have originally thought the (incorrect, negated version of the) statement was a simple exercise. But in fact the correct version is pretty sophisticated, and beyond what is reasonable to expect someone reading this book to do.

@SamHopkins
I resorted to the chinese version of its textbook for this problem. And the newest 2nd edition for english version had the problem phrased in a way that is impossible to accomplish, which is wrong. I have also seen posts on chinese forum saying that the correct version of the problem is highly complicated. So I think you are correct in stating its complexity. Thank you for your response, but I still want to seek for an answer.

This ia not an answer but it does suggest why the question is quite subtle-- if two functìons on a set commute and one has a unique fixed point, then the second one also has a fixed point (any set, no topological conditions, completely trivial proof).

W. M. Boyce and J. P. Huneke provided counterexamples in papers that appeared in Transactions of the American Mathematical Society in 1969.

wonderful answer!
